# Microsoft Graph API auth - Scope is not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've successfully followed the basic tutorial of connecting a RailsOnRails app with Microsoft Graph API, provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/ruby?tutorial-step=3

As suggested, I've put in the scope from the tutorial, just to see if it will work `openid email profile User.Read` and it does!

Now I'm trying to expand to the scope and read emails too, but when I try adding `Mail.ReadBasic` I get the error:

```
The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope "openid email profile User.Read Mail.ReadBasic" doesn't exist.
```

I've tried with `Mail.Read`, that works, but that's not what I need. I need exactly `Mail.ReadBasic`.

This is the example of the request I'm making towards Microsoft:

`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=XXX&scope=openid profile email offline_access User.Read Mail.ReadBasic&redirect_uri=https://my-redirect-uri&response_type=code&state=XXX&uaid=XXX&msproxy=1&issuer=mso&tenant=common&ui_locales=en-US&username=XXX`

I've also tried prefixing the scope with `https://graph.microsoft.com/` as suggested in number of other questions, but it didn't work either.

What might be the issue? Is there a way of specifying this limited scope for reading emails?

Comment: Could you please include your request sample on your question?

Comment: I just did. Hope it helps.

Comment: You cannot define multiple `scope` together like this `User.Read Mail.ReadBasic` either you have write  `User.Read` or `Mail.ReadBasic`. Microsoft Authentication protocol doesn't support multiple  scope.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because combination of `User.Read Mail.Read` works without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your OAuth request is being sent to the incorrect URI. It should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/`

According to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/ruby?tutorial-step=3), you should be using these settings:

```rb
# Configure the Microsoft identity platform endpoints
option  :client_options,
         site:          'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
         authorize_url: '/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
         token_url:     '/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Your scopes should be URL Encoded.